# Python3: Recursive functioin not returning value in compiler mode

Tags: python-3.x, recursion, factorial

```
def factorial(n):
    if n == 0:
        return(1)
    else:
        return(n * factorial(n-1))

factorial(5)
```

This code does not return the factorial of 5 or any other value when I run it in the compiler but returns correct value when run in interpreter mode.

Also same thing is happening with other programs where I use recursion.

```
def insert(seq,k):
    pos = 1
    while pos > 0 and seq[pos] < seq[pos-1]:
        (seq[pos], seq[pos-1]) = (seq[pos-1], seq[pos])
        pos = pos - 1

def isort(seq,k):
    if k > 1:
        isort(seq,k-1)
        insert(seq,k-1)
    else:
        return

def InsertionSort(seq):
    isort(seq,len(seq))
    return(seq)

InsertionSort([4,56,15,86,84,3,51,2,4,1,54,5,1,87,5,2,7,15,65])
```

I apologise for asking trivial thing, I have just started learning python

Comment: What is "compiler mode"? Are you referring to some specific IDE feature?

Comment: @ReutSharabani By "compiler mode " I mean executing as a script in IDLE or Spyder

Comment: @Carcigenicate Can you please tell the specific syntax, sorry for my noobness

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, it *is* returning it, it's just that nothing is *using* the returned value.

In the *interactive* interpreter, the REPL<sup>(a)</sup> will output the value of an expression if it's not `None`.

That is *not* the case when running a script, you need to *explicitly* print it:

```
print(factorial(5))
```

---

<sup>(a)</sup> This is the `Read-Eval-Print-Loop` and you should take *extra* notice of that `Print` bit, it's important in this context :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try to print your result.
Exemple : `print(factorial(5))`